# What does "while(node!=NULL&&node->next!=NULL)" signify in linked list. How to use it efficiently

Tags: c++

I'm confused about this while condition.

My thinking is that if I already check `node!=NULL` then what is the use of checking `node->next!=NULL` in this case...

*Removal of every kth node in the linked list*

```
Node* delete(Node *A,int k)
{
if(A==NULL)
    return NULL;
if(A->next==NULL&&k==1)
    return NULL;
if(k==1)
    return NULL;
Node * head = A;
Node * ptr;
int count = 1;
**while(head!=NULL&&head->next!=NULL)**{
    if(count == k-1){
        ptr=head->next;
        head->next=head->next->next;
        free(ptr);
        count=1;
        head=head->next;
    }
    else{
    head=head->next;
    count++;    
    }
}
return A;
```

}

Comment: Hint: what is the precondition for `head->next->next` to be valid?

Comment: If you want efficiency, you (1) don't use a linked list at all; or (2) if you have to anyway, use std::list.

Comment: When `k==1`, the nodes are not freed as they should.

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book and this [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Use a debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) to understand the behavior of your C++ code. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile it with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: Wrong C++ code since `delete` is a keyword. It won't compile

Comment: It tells you if `head` is NOT null and `head->next` is ALSO not null. Like it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

head->next checks if there is any node next to the head. It is important to check here, because you are assigning

```
head->next = head->next->next;
```

In case you don't check head->next != NULL and suppose there is no next node to the head or head->next = NULL, then it will lead to segmentation fault as it will try to find the next of a nullptr, which do not exists.

Answer (score 0):

> My thinking is that if I already check node!=NULL then what is the use of checking node->next!=NULL in this case...

The first time into the loop, we know `head` is not null, as `head` is `A` and we've already checked `A` for null.

Subsequently, we iterate in the loop only if `head->next` is not null. If we delete, then the new value of `head` is `head->next->next` which we haven't yet checked for null. So we do need to check both `head` and `head->next` for at least some of the paths around the loop, but you're right that we don't need to check both for all paths.

This, for example, is also safe, and avoids checking `head` on every iteration:

```
Node * head = A; // head is not null as we checked A
int count = 1;

while (head->next != NULL) {
    if (count == k-1) {
        Node *ptr = head->next; // not null, checked above
        head->next = head->next->next; // maybe null
        free(ptr);
        count = 1;
        head = head->next; // maybe null
        if (head == NULL) break; // so check here
    } else {
        head=head->next; // not null due to check in while condition
        count++;    
    }
}
```

There are other combinations of checks which are also safe; unless there's a known performance problem it's usually better to have redundant checks than forcing the next developer to think through all possible paths through the code.

Also these returns doesn't fit with the pattern in the rest of the code, which frees all the nodes which are not reachable from the returned pointer:

```
if(A->next==NULL&&k==1)
    return NULL;
if(k==1)
    return NULL;
```

Both don't delete anything and the second condition matches everything in the first, so only the second is needed.